# Firefox not loading images

Tags: html, firefox

I just uploaded a website, www.thedesignemperium.com . Problem is, my gallery images load fine on other browsers, but not on firefox. What could be causing this? Assistance would be appreciated much.

Comment: Check the console for any errors?

Comment: I checked it went on fine. What are the images missing ?

Comment: Its working fine for me... Which version of ff are u using?

Comment: Make sure you don't have an old not-working page in cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you're selecting the file path of your images via a backslash. This can be seen in the error messages in the console:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.thedesignemperium.com/img%5Cimg2.png"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.thedesignemperium.com/img%5Cbox.jpg"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.thedesignemperium.com/img%5Csweet.jpg"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.thedesignemperium.com/img%5Cimg.png"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.thedesignemperium.com/img%5Cres8.jpg"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.thedesignemperium.com/img%5Cimg2.png"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.thedesignemperium.com/img%5Cbox.jpg"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.thedesignemperium.com/img%5Csweet.jpg"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.thedesignemperium.com/img%5Cimg.png"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.thedesignemperium.com/img%5Cres8.jpg"
```

These all say the location doesn't exist for those files. If you'd open the urls, you'd see there's a backslash in the URL instead of a forward slash (`%5C` decodes to `\` in URLs). Other browsers have built-in error handling to redirect backslashes to forward slashes, but they are not required to do this: Firefox is not wrong here, your URLs are.

To fix this, just replace all backslashes in your urls with forward slashes.